# How to get multiple rows into single row with different columns

Tags: mysql

I'm having the following table structure and the expected output is listed below how to achieve the result :

**Gender - Countvalue**

Male - 9

Female - 4

**Expected output :**

Male - Female

9  -  4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT  
        max(case when `gender` = 'Male' then countvalue end) as Male,
        max(case when `gender` = 'Female' then countvalue end) as Female
FROM    test
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7aa49/5)**

Answer (score 1):

```
create table k
(   gender varchar(20) not null,
    theCount int not null
);
insert k(gender,theCount) values ('male',9),('female',4);


select a.theCount as male, b.theCount as female 
from k a 
cross join k b 
where a.gender='male' and b.gender='female';

+------+--------+
| male | female |
+------+--------+
|    9 |      4 |
+------+--------+
```

A cross join is a cartesian product. But 1 row by 1 row is 1 row in result set.

Comment: and the cross join would be replaced by a regular self-join in most applications (join made on some other field).

Comment: we would need to examine the schema of such. I showed one. OP didn't. Devil's in the details. So I am looking at your tag specialties, @user3580870. Help me here

Comment: I like interesting questions. This is one. Like to avoid an unnecessary pivot table

Comment: in a real application OP probably meant to have gender counts for each category, for example, each state in US. in this case, one would self-join "on" the state field.

Comment: I am all for real world schemas @user3580870  :)